# Automate data loading to Google Sheet from PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

I would like to create an automated data pulling from our PostgreSQL database to a Google sheet. I've tried JDBC service, but it doesn't work, maybe incorrect variables/config. Does anyone already try doing this? I'd also like to schedule the extraction every hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), only Google Cloud SQL MySQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases are supported by Apps Script's JDBC. You may have to either move to a new database or develop your own API services to handle the connection.

As for scheduling by the hour, you can use Apps Script's [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).